# Regex thousand operator either , or

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a python Regex and I'm receiving numbers with either a , as a thousand sign or a . If the , is the thousand sign then a . is the decimal sign and vice versa. The only positive thing there though is that there are always two decimal numbers.

I need to regex these number and I don't care about the decimal number so I would like to extract the following. Can someone smarter than me help? This is giving me a headache.

```
111.112.123,55 -> 111112123
123.44         -> 123
123,353,123.55 -> 123353123
21,23          -> 21
152.00         -> 152
```

Comment: [`re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[.,](?=\d)|(?<=\d[,.])\d\d$', '')`](https://regex101.com/r/cvC4V0/15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
[,.]\d+$|[.,]
```

- `[,.]` Character set for either `,` or `.`.
- `\d+$` Digits at end of string.
- `|`    Alternation (OR).
- `[.,]` Character set for either `,` or `.`.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iUKC0Z/1).

---

Python demo:

```
import re
mynumbers=['111.112.123,55','123.44','123,353,123.55','21,23','152.00']

for number in mynumbers:
    print(re.sub(r'[,.]\d+$|[.,]','',number))
```

Prints:

```
111112123
123
123353123
21
152
```

---

You may alternatively use a more restrictive pattern if you are working with text:

```
[.,]\d+$|(?<=\d{3})[.,]
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iUKC0Z/3).

Python:

```
mytext = '''
111.112.123,55
123.44
123,353,123.55
21,23
152.00
Text, and punctuation.
'''

for line in mytext.splitlines():
    print(re.sub(r'[.,]\d+$|(?<=\d{3})[.,]','',line))
```

Prints:

```
111112123
123
123353123
21
152
Text, and punctuation.
```

Comment: This works if they're just receiving numbers (which they probably are). If you're reading a file with other content as well then my comment will be a bit more specific. Something like "8.31.2018" could potentially break it.

Comment: Yeah, but [your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cvC4V0/14) would also match punctuation characters in normal text.

Comment: Yeah I suppose that's true. That can be dealt with using lookarounds, but I won't bother unless OP specifically needs that.

Comment: That works too. I updated my comment because I've got nothing better to do right now

Comment: I feel you, you should post it as an answer then :) Perhaps worth nothing that with your latest pattern only two decimals are replaced (that is what OP shows, true), it won't remove a single digit or more.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are dealing with strings that only contain one number, you can use this pattern:

```
re.sub(r'[.,](?:\d\d$)?', '', s)
```

*(a , or a . eventually followed by 2 digits and the end of the string.)*

Answer (score 1):

You could capture one or more digits in a capturing group `(\d+)` followed by a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[.,]` that matches either a dot or a comma.

To match the digits at the end you could use an optional non capturing group `(?:\d+$)?` that would match one or more times a digit followed by asserting the end of the line. You might start the match with a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to prevent it from being part of a longer match

In the replacement use the first capturing group `\1`

`\b(\d+)[.,](?:\d+$)?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M8tuod/1)

[Python demo](http://rextester.com/UWAKT11630)